# How to list questions that have a vote to reopen on questions that I previously voted to close

Tags: support, closing, reopen

Scenario:

1. I vote to close a question, which is subsequently closed.
2. The OP and/or others fix the question.
3. Someone votes to reopen.

---

How can I efficiently find such questions?

The purpose is to vote to reopen if my original concerns with the question are now resolved.

I occasionally bump back into such questions (by chance), which allows me to issue my own vote to reopen, if I deem it necessary.  However, it seems like the SE way is to favour a set of different people to vote to reopen questions.  I cannot confirm for sure, but I don't believe I have every reviewed an item in the re-open queue that I previously voted to close (could be mistaken/coincidence, perhaps).

The only method I see at the moment is to go through my review history, one click at a time.  Obviously, this is not very efficient.

---

Additionally, from the OP's perspective is could be useful having VTC users being more proactive in their reversals once a question has been fixed.  This seems to only really occur if I leave a comment detailing my vote reason, and someone replies to the comment.

---

Finally, I don't want to track every review I ever made or intend to vigorously monitor questions I have voted on.  I would like a simple way of getting to a list of questions that meet the scenario detailed.

Comment: I did get an item in the reopen queue earlier today that I voted to close.

Comment: Easiest way is probably to favourite them (click the star under the vote count), then check your 'favourites' tab on your user profile. Activity (edits, answers etc) will bump them in there. You can then potentially unfavourite once/if the question is reopened.

Comment: The only problem is that you need to anticipate that the question may be reopened.  A reasonable proposal if you feel there is potential in an off-topic question perhaps.

Comment: I don't understand the concern. If it gets enough reopen votes before you get on again, then it's reopened whether you voted or not. If it doesn't, you'll see it in the review queue.